# Drawing fractals using recursion

Tags: python, recursion, turtle-graphics, fractals

Recently i started learning about recursion and i noticed there is something called fractals , i made simple tree with it.

But i have a problem with getting the recursion idea of this fractal https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Pap4.png

i saw something like it but made with squares.

Can any one explain the recursion idea for this one ?
I tried this algorithm with Python(turtle)

```
def fractal(start,length,direction,t):

    if(length < 10):

       return

    t.rt(direction)

    direction = int(direction/360) # To make it only {90,-90}

    t.fd(length)

    fractal(start+length,length/2,direction+90,t)

    fractal(start+length,length/2,direction-90,t)

    t.lt(direction)

    fractal(start+length,length/2,direction+90,t)

    fractal(start+length,length/2,direction-90,t)
```

Comment: What exactly is the question? The basic form seems to be a letter `H` with smaller versions of itself at each of the endpoints.

Comment: I want to draw the shape in the picture(url), i tries the code above it didn't work and gave me a wrong shape i need to know if the algorithm is wrong or what ?

Comment: @AbdullatifB. You can learn more about ***fractal*** and ***recursion*** using ***python*** from [The Nature of Code](https://natureofcode.com/book/chapter-8-fractals/)

Comment: @eapetcho i saw his videos , but i can't draw the fractal in the picture

Comment: Draw first line. Then repeat: at each line endpoint - draw perpendicular line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic shape of the fractal is a large letter "H" with smaller versions of itself at each of its four tips. So what you basically have to do is draw an "H" in turtle, and whenever you are at the tips, call `fractal` again with half the length. Keep in mind that the turtle should always be oriented in the same direction when the function starts, and has to return to the origin after drawing the shape. The function could look somewhat like this:

```
def fractal(length, t):
    if length >= 10 :
        # draw left side 
        t.lt(90)
        t.fd(length)
        t.rt(90)
        t.fd(length)
        fractal(length//2, t)
        t.bk(length*2)
        fractal(length//2, t)
        t.fd(length)
        # draw right side
        t.rt(90)
        t.fd(length*2)
        t.lt(90)
        t.fd(length)
        fractal(length//2, t)
        t.bk(length*2)
        fractal(length//2, t)
        t.fd(length)
        # back to origin
        t.lt(90)
        t.fd(length)
        t.rt(90)
```

You could also use that fact that both sides of te figure are symmetrical:

```
def fractal(length, t):
    if length >= 10:
        t.rt(90)
        side(length, t)
        t.rt(180)
        side(length, t)
        t.rt(90)

def side(length, t):
    t.fd(length)
    t.rt(90)
    t.fd(length)
    fractal(length//2, t)
    t.bk(length*2)
    fractal(length//2, t)
    t.fd(length)
    t.lt(90)
    t.bk(length)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not the fastest implementation but it's compact and keeps you guessing where it's going next:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

def fractal(turtle, length, minimum):

    if length < minimum:
        return

    angle = 90
    length //= 2

    for _ in range(2):
        for _ in range(2):
            turtle.forward(length)
            turtle.left(angle)
            turtle.forward(length)
            turtle.left(angle)
            fractal(turtle, length, minimum)
            turtle.left(angle)
            turtle.forward(length)
            turtle.right(angle)
            turtle.forward(length)

        angle = -angle

screen = Screen()

yertle = Turtle()
yertle.speed('fastest')  # because I have no patience

fractal(yertle, 100, 10)

screen.exitonclick()
```

First we draw our way to the upper right leg of the H, turn inward and recurse.  Once we finish the recursion, we continue turning in the same direction to move back down the arm.  Instead of moving all the way down the arm (the efficient thing to do) we return to our starting point but now we're facing the opposite way so we simply repeat everything we've done until now to draw the lower left of the H.

Once that finishes, we're back at the center pointing in the original direction again, so we repeat the whole process again but turn all our rights into lefts, and vice versa, by negating the angle.  This draws our lower left leg and then finishes with the upper right leg.

[image]